# Worklight PDF Containerization

Tags: pdf, ibm-mobilefirst

Has anyone come across a solution or best practice to downloading PDFs from a worklight adapter to a device, encrypting it and ensuring the PDF can not be shared via email, iBooks etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the options provided in the answers in the following question, to get the PDF:  [Worklight Adapter getting pdf file from rest service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839302/worklight-adapter-getting-pdf-file-from-rest-service)

And the couple the above with [encrypting and storing it using JSONStore](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced-client-side-development).

This way I believe the data is both encrypted as well as not available to other apps.