# Read PDF File from IBM Worklight 6.1

Tags: java, android, tomcat, pdf, ibm-mobilefirst

My requirement is to develop an app using IBM **Worklight 6.1** which will get the file from web server and show it to the user without downloading it.

For that i did the following steps:-

1. First Created an Worklight Project
2. In that project created an java package and trying to access the PDF file from Apache Tomcat.
3. I am using PDFBOX to read the file from Apache tomcat.
4. I am going to receive the PDF text from adapter.
5. From the adapter, i am going to send it to the client side and showing to the user.

I followed the following link to generate JAVA code:

http://www.ehow.com/how_6582916_read-pdf-file-java.html

The code is as follows:-

```
public static String sendPDF(){
    PDFTextParser pdf = new PDFTextParser("path to pdf in tomcat");
    return pdf.getParsedText();
}
```

Now the problem is:-

Using this path "path to pdf file in tomcat" the pdfbox is unable to access the file. I am trying to use servletcontext, so i included servlet-api.jar. Still i am unable to access the pdf file. I need a way to access the file. Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Can you provide the url what you have tried to access the file from webserver. 2.can you please share if any errors displayed.

Comment: 1. The url is http://localhost:8080/pdf/example.pdf 2.The error displaying is " file http://localhost:8080/pdf/example.pdf is not found "

Comment: I can able to read the file from any drive. But the problem is accessing the file in tomcat

Comment: I updated my answer in case the problem was to open an URL instead of a local file.

Comment: The problem is to accessing file from Tomcat Server. So i need to know how exactly we can access it.

Comment: Maybe clarify - is it a file or an URL? If it is an URL, you can't access it without converting it to an inputStream.

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839302/worklight-adapter-getting-pdf-file-from-rest-service/19920764#19920764

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to open a PDF url with PDFBox is like this:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new URL("http://www.host.com/xxx.pdf").openStream());
```

Even better is to use the non sequential parser:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new URL("http://www.host.com/xxx.pdf").openStream(), null);
```

To learn more about text extraction, look at the source code of ExtractImages, which you will find [here](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/1.8/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/ExtractText.java?view=markup&sortby=date).