# Display PDF from server using IBM Worklight

Tags: java, pdf, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to display the PDF file from apache tomcat using IBM Worklight. Using the following link [Worklight Adapter getting pdf file from rest service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839302/worklight-adapter-getting-pdf-file-from-rest-service), i converted the PDF file into Byte Array.
In the client side, the code is

```
var pdfText = decodeURIComponent(response.invocationResult.pdf);
var pdf = base64DecToArr(pdfText);
PDFJS.getDocument(pdf).then(iterate);
```

But i am unable to display the file. When running the following code on emulator, it is not displaying any error. When running the same code in chrome browser, 
Error: Invalid XRef stream header util.js:186
    at error 
Warning: Unsupported feature "unknown" util.js:171
Warning: Unsupported feature "unknown" util.js:171
Warning: Indexing all PDF objects

I need to know how to display the [Object Uint8Array] as PDF.

Comment: And the targeted mobile environment is.........?

Comment: Currently i am targeting on Android

Answer (score 0):

Android has no native PDf viewer capability in their browser (unlike Safari in iOS), so simply receiving a PDF and converting/opening it in the webview isn't going to work.

Two options from here: [Phonegap InAppBrowser display pdf 2.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795172/phonegap-inappbrowser-display-pdf-2-7-0)

1. Don't download the PDF; instead redirect to the online view capabilities of Google Doc Viewer, as stated in [this StackOverflow answer](https://github.com/markeeftb/FileOpener)
2. Download the file and use the [FileOpener Cordova plug-in](https://github.com/markeeftb/FileOpener). This will either open the file in an *installed PDF reader app* or present the user with a choice.

You could also always opt to [write your own custom Cordova plug-in](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova)(Getting Started training module) in Worklight that will [implement some native code to view PDFs in Android](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=stackoverflow:%20android%20display%20pdf&safe=off).

Comment: I am getting the pdf file as [Object Uint8Array] through rest services only, as i mentioned in the question. In that case, how can i pass the [Object Uint8Array] to display as a pdf file using javascript or any other 3rd party plugin.

Comment: Read the Cordova plug-in training modules I linked to... the API allows to send data to the plug-in.