# Get PDF files from Worklight Server to the client

Tags: pdf, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Based on the following reference:- [Worklight Adapter getting pdf file from rest service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839302/worklight-adapter-getting-pdf-file-from-rest-service/19920764?noredirect=1), i got the PDF file from tomcat server through the worklight adapter. The server side code is:-

```
var input = {
method : 'get',
returnedContentType : 'plain',
path : '/PDF/example-abstract.pdf'
};  
return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

When i invoke the invoke the procedure i am able to successfully retrieve the result. When i invoke the same procedure from client side like below:-

```
var invocationData = {
        adapter: 'PdfReader',
        procedure: 'readPDF',
        parameters: []
};
```

I am unable to receive the response in the success handler. In logcat it showing the following error:-

```
    07-03 13:07:05.330: E/pdf(4214): [http://Path-to-pdf:10080/pdf/apps/services/api/pdf/android/query] exception. SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL  
07-03 13:07:05.377: D/dalvikvm(4214): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 347K, 10% free 8082K/8967K, paused 19ms  
07-03 13:07:05.424: D/dalvikvm(4214): GC_CONCURRENT freed 155K, 7% free 8390K/8967K, paused 2ms+3ms  
07-03 13:07:05.424: D/pdf(4214): response [http://Path-to-pdf:10080/pdf/apps/services/api/pdf/android/query] success: {"responseID":"2","statusCode":200,"text":"%PDF-1.4\n%????\n3 0 obj <<\n\/Length 2445      \n\/Filter \/FlateDecode\n>>\nstream\nx?X[??\n~?_?#?YQ?O?dw??M??3?4'\u000f0 \\Shorted  
07-03 13:07:05.424: W/PluginManager(4214): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Logger.DEBUG blocked the main thread for 45ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().  
07-03 13:07:05.455: E/pdf(4214): [http://Path-to-pdf:10080/pdf/apps/services/api/pdf/android/query] exception. TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSuccessful' of undefined  
07-03 13:07:05.455: D/CordovaLog(4214): file:///data/data/com.pdf/files/www/default/worklight/worklight.js: Line 3320 : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL  
07-03 13:07:05.455: E/Web Console(4214): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL at file:///data/data/com.pdf/files/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:3320  
07-03 13:07:05.463: D/CordovaLog(4214): file:///data/data/com.pdf/files/www/default/worklight/worklight.js: Line 3320 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSuccessful' of undefined  
07-03 13:07:05.471: E/Web Console(4214): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSuccessful' of undefined at file:///data/data/com.pdf/files/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:3320
```

I need to know, how to make it reachable in the successHandler. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with parsing the JSON data, based on the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432165/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-with-json-parse), I have converted the Json data to string using **JSON.stringify()**, so that the string can successfully reach the successHandler inside the handler i am using **JSON.parse()** to convert the string to JSON for use.